# Polynomial size CFG such that each terminal in a word occurs even number of times (large alphabet)

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

Find a context-free grammar (CFG) for the language L of all
words such that each terminal in a word occurs even number of times over a possibly large alphabet Σ

<strike>My long aproach is (the only nonterminal is S):</strike>

> S ⟶ ε | SS
>
> x ∈ Σ : S ⟶ xSx
>
> x,y ∈ Σ : S ⟶ xxSyy | yySxx | xySxy | xySyx | yxSyx | yxSyx

Is this correct?
The productions generate correct words, do they generate all words?

EDIT: Can a CFG over large alphabet describe a language, where each terminal appears even number of times?

EDIT_2: If a solution exists, is it possible Chomsky Normal Form be polynomial in |Σ| ?

Comment: for sigma = {'1', '2', '3', '4'... }, I don't think this can generate '12344123', even though it appears to be in the definition of L

Comment: >"I don't think this can generate '12344123'". I think it can. A parser confirm this.

Comment: For reference: nowadays, there is [cs.SE] for all kinds of computer science questions. Mind the *science*, though; programming if offtopic, even though applied sciency questions are ontopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is even a regular grammar to achieve this. Since every regular grammar is by definition context-free, the answer ist "yes". It's also possible to construct a finite automaton, but since you asked for a grammar...

Here's how: recall that a regular grammar allows rules of the form A -> b C or A -> b or A -> epsilon, where A and C are non-terminals and b is a terminal. This essentially means that every non-terminal generates a terminal and another non-terminal which will generate the rest of the string; we could say that every non-terminal encodes a certain property about the strings it generates.

Consider now all the subsets of  the alphabet Sigma. Since Sigma is supposed to be finite, so is the set of subsets (powerset). Let the set of non-terminals be the powerset of Sigma.

Start with a rule: {} -> a {a} for every terminal a.
For every non-terminal X, add the rule X -> a X-{a} if a is in X; or X -> a X+{a} if a is not in X
(I'm sloppily writing + and - for set union and difference here).

Finally, add {} -> epsilon (the empty word).

The grammar encodes in its non-terminals exactly the sets of terminals which have appeared in an odd number and thus have to be "canceled out" again.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to get your idea. Are you sure this will work for palindromes in the language?

Comment: For a start I completely fail to understand this: "Let the set of non-terminals be the powerset of Sigma."

Comment: There is another (completely analogous) construction of a finite automaton over at mathSE; maybe you are more familiar with automata and can understand it more easily. Anyway: non-terminals can be any symbols, and symbols are just arbitrary objects, so we choose the subsets of Sigma to be our non-terminals. As for the palindromes, why would it not work? We are not designing a grammar for the palindrome language (which by the way is context-free), but for a language which is a superset of the palindromes. But this is not a special property; in fact, even Sigma* is a superset of the palindromes.

Comment: Thank you all! If you find a polynomial size CFG, feel free to comment again! I will bet my construction is wrong + parsers lied :-(